# $.getJSON not working for url

Tags: json, facebook, getjson

```
<html>
   <head>
        <script src = "jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/zombies',function(results){
                    document.write(results.can_post);

});

});
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

This code works for the above url, but when I use a different url, it doesn't work. $.getJSON fails to work for http://my-proxy-app12.appspot.com/query?id=ahBzfm15LXByb3h5LWFwcDEychULEghBcGlRdWVyeRiAgICAvKGCCgw&format=json when I try to grab data from it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: The first URL is [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)-enabled, the second one isn’t. Meaning, you can not request the second one via AJAX from a different domain. (Unless it is under your control(?), then you can enable CORS for that resource.)